# Plugin to add voting in posts like digg

Tags: vbulletin

Is there any plug-in that i can use with vBulletin to add thumbs up or down kind of voting to all posts?

I want to allow people to vote up or down on every post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got my solution i found product for vBulletin which is called "Helpful Answers", it has thumbs up and down feature like i wanted and has couple of other features too.